# Reading text file in php with variables and data records as multiple rows

Tags: php, arrays

I need your help in reading text file in `php` the first part of the file consists of variables and the second part consist of data as multiple rows, each row limits is 79.

I want to read the data and store them in `mysql` db.

The file is [epiData rec file](http://www.epidata.dk/downloads/epidata_datafile.pdf)

The file structure as below:

```
44 1
_COUNTRY       1   3  30  57   3   3   3 112 COUNTRY         Country ............................... 
_IDCODE        1   4  30  57   4   3  20 112 IDCODE          EPID No................................ 
#HOTCASE       1   5  30  57   5   0   1 112 HOTCASE         Hot case............................... 
_DISTRICT      1   6  30  57   6   3  20 112 DISTRICT        District............................... 
_PROVINCE      1   7  30  57   7   3  20 112 PROVINCE        Province............................... 
_DOB           1   8  30  57   8  11  10 112 DOB             Date of birth.......................... 
#AGE           1   9  30  57   9   0   3 112 AGE             Age (in months)........................ 
#SEX           1  10  30  57  10   0   1 112 SEX             Sex.................................... 
_DONSET        1  11  30  57  11  11  10 112 DONSET          Date of onset of paralysis............. 
_DNOT          1  12  30  57  12  11  10 112 DNOT            Date of notification................... 
_DOI           1  13  30  57  13  11  10 112 DOI             Date of case investigation............. 
_DSTCOLL1      1  14  30  57  14  11  10 112 DSTCOLL1        Date stool collected:1................. 
_DSTCOLL2      1  15  30  57  15  11  10 112 DSTCOLL2        Date stool collected:2 ................ 
#DOSESR        1  16  30  57  16   0   1 112 DOSESR          Routine doses of OPV................... 
#DOSESN        1  17  30  57  17   0   2 112 DOSESN          Doses of OPV during NID/SIA............ 
#DOSES         1  18  30  57  18   0   2 112 DOSES           Total polio doses...................... 
_DLOPV         1  19  30  57  19  11  10 112 DLOPV           Date of last OPV....................... 
#FEVER         1  20  30  57  20   0   1 112 FEVER           Fever.................................. 
#PROGRESS      1  21  30  57  21   0   1 112 PROGRESS        Progression............................ 
#ASYM          1  22  30  57  22   0   1 112 ASYM            Asymmetric paralysis................... 
_DFUP          1  23  30  57  23  11  10 112 DFUP            Date of follow-up...................... 
#FUP           1  24  30  57  24   0   1 112 FUP             Findings at follow-up.................. 
_DSTLAB        1  25  30  57  25  11  10 112 DSTLAB          Date stool(s) received in lab.......... 
_DTRES         1  26  30  57  26  11  10 112 DTRES           Date prelim results received by EPI.... 
_DIRES         1  27  30  57  27  11  10 112 DIRES           Date ITD results received by EPI....... 
#STCOND        1  28  30  57  28   0   1 112 STCOND          Stool condition... .................... 
#L20B          1  29  30  57  29   0   1 112 L20B            L20B isolated.......................... 
#P1            1  30  30  57  30   0   1 112 P1              P1 (lab results)....................... 
#P2            1  31  30  57  31   0   1 112 P2              P2 (lab results)....................... 
#P3            1  32  30  57  32   0   1 112 P3              P3 (lab results)....................... 
#ENTERO        1  33  30  57  33   0   1 112 ENTERO          Entero (lab results)................... 
#CLASS         1  34  30  57  34   0   1 112 CLASS           Classification......................... 
#FDIAG         1  35  30  57  35   0   1 112 FDIAG           Final diagnosis... .................... 
_OTHDIAG       1  36  30  57  36   3   6 112 OTHDIAG         Diagnosis (if FDIAG=Other)............. 
_SDIAG         1  37  30  57  37   1  40 112 SDIAG           Specify diagnosis (if OTHDIAG=Other)... 
#CONTACT       1  38  30  57  38   0   1 112 CONTACT         Number of contacts..................... 
#ELIGCONT      1  39  30  57  39   0   1 112 ELIGCONT        AFP case eligible for contacts......... 
#INADAFP       1  40  30  57  40   0   1 112 INADAFP         Reason for contact - inadequate........ 
#HOTAFP        1  41  30  57  41   0   1 112 HOTAFP          Reason for contact - hot AFP........... 
#HARDAREA      1  42  30  57  42   0   1 112 HARDAREA        Reason for contact - area.............. 
#OTHREAS       1  43  30  57  43   0   1 112 OTHREAS         Reason for contact - other............. 
_SOTHREAS      1  44  30  57  44   1  30 112 SOTHREAS        Other reason, specify.................. 
#WILDCONT      1  45  30  57  45   0   1 112 WILDCONT        Wild poliovirus from contacts.......... 
#VDPVCONT      1  46  30  57  46   0   1 112 VDPVCONT        VDPV isolated from contacts............ 
AFGAFG/06/06/725       2KABUL               KABUL                          242!
18/09/2006                    22/09/200623/09/20060  9918/09/2006             !
 26/09/2006                    12444134                                       !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/11/370       2MUSAYI              KABUL                          602!
22/11/2014                    25/11/201427/11/20140  9927/10/2014             !
 29/11/201411/12/2014          12444234                                       !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/07/101       2BAMYAN              BAMYAN                        9001!
                                                  0  9905/08/2007             !
                                                                              !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/17/005       2SAYDABAD            WARDAK                         541!
02/01/201704/01/201704/01/201704/01/201705/01/20175131818/10/2016111          !
 10/01/201721/01/2017          12444235G04                                    !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/17/007       1WARAS               BAMYAN                          61!
01/01/201704/01/201704/01/201704/01/201705/01/20174 3 718/10/2016111          !
 10/01/201721/01/2017          12444235B34                                    !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/17/002       2KABUL               KABUL                          181!
01/01/201701/01/201701/01/201702/01/201707/01/20175 61117/10/2016111          !
 07/01/201719/01/2017          12444235G81                                    !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/17/003       2SHEKHALI            PARWAN                         441!
01/01/201703/01/201703/01/201703/01/201705/01/20174141816/10/2016112          !
 07/01/201719/01/2017          12444235E87.6                                  !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/17/008       2NERKH               WARDAK                         482!
03/01/201704/01/201704/01/201705/01/201706/01/20175121718/10/2016111          !
 10/01/201721/01/2017          12444235B34                                    !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/17/001       2KHENJ (HES-E- AWAL) PANJSHER                       142!
01/01/201702/01/201702/01/201702/01/201703/01/20175 4 917/10/2016111          !
 05/01/201716/01/2017          12444235B34                                    !
                                             !
AFGAFG/05/17/004       2KABUL               KABUL                          362!
01/01/201702/01/201702/01/201702/01/201704/01/20175 71214/12/2016111          !
 06/01/201717/01/2017          12444235B34                                    !
                                             !
```

The first line in the file lists the number of variables `44`, and the 8th column is the length for each variable (before 112 column) I managed to read the variables and put them in an array but I face a problem how to read the data for each variable.

I will show how I accomplished that:

```
<?php

$file_name = 'CTRYAFP10.rec';

if (file_exists($file_name)) {
    $file = fopen($file_name, "r");

    $first_row = fgets($file);
    //I used fgets() to read the file row by row

    $first_row_array = explode(" ", trim($first_row));

    $numberOfVariables = intval($first_row_array[0]);

    $total_length_for_all_varibles = 0;
    $number_of_data_rows = 0;

    $j = 0;
    $heads = array();
    $last_end = null;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfVariables; $i++) {
        $result = fgets($file);
        $variable_name = strtolower(trim(substr($result, 1, 11)));
        $current_item_length = intval(trim(substr($result, 36, 4)));
        $total_length_for_all_varibles += $current_item_length;
        $last_end = $current_item_length + intval($last_end);

        if ($current_item_length > 0) {
            if ($i === 0) {
                //first loop
                $heads[$i]['start'] = 0;//variable starts at position 0 of the row
            } else {
                $prev_start = $heads[$i - 1]['start'];
                $prev_item_length = $heads[$i - 1]['field_length'];

                $x = $prev_start + $prev_item_length;
                $data_row_limit = 79 - $x;//the limits of each data row is 79
                if($data_row_limit > $current_item_length){
                    $heads[$i]['start'] = $x;
                } else {
                    $heads[$i]['start'] = 0;
                }
            }

            $heads[$i]['field_length'] = $current_item_length;
            $heads[$i]['variable_name'] = strtolower(trim($variable_name));

        }//end if length > 0
    }//end for loop for getting the variables

    $number_of_data_rows = ceil($total_length_for_all_varibles/79);// in this case 4
    $total_length_for_all_varibles +=  $number_of_data_rows;//in this case its 283

    //while (!feof($file)){
        $data = '';
        $insert_data = array();
        for($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_data_rows; $i++){
            $data .= fgets($file);
        }
/*
The output for the previous loop which represents (the data/empty value) for the 44 variables
AFGAFG/06/06/725       2KABUL               KABUL                          242!
18/09/2006                    22/09/200623/09/20060  9918/09/2006             !
 26/09/2006                    12444134                                       !
                                             !
*/
        foreach ($heads as $key => $val){
            $item_val = trim(substr($data, $val['start'], $val['field_length']));
            $insert_data[$val['variable_name']] = $item_val;
        }

    var_dump($insert_data);exit();
    //}

}
```

The output for the above code is, it reads till `["sex"]` variable correct values but it doesn't continue to the second row after 79 charachter popsition:

```
array(44) {                                           
  ["country"]=>                                       
  string(3) "AFG"                                     
  ["idcode"]=>                                        
  string(13) "AFG/06/06/725"                          
  ["hotcase"]=>                                       
  string(1) "2"                                       
  ["district"]=>                                      
  string(5) "KABUL"                                   
  ["province"]=>                                      
  string(5) "KABUL"                                   
  ["dob"]=>                                           
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["age"]=>                                           
  string(2) "24"                                      
  ["sex"]=>                                           
  string(1) "2"                                       
  ["donset"]=>                                        
  string(10) "AFGAFG/06/"                             
  ["dnot"]=>                                          
  string(6) "06/725"                                  
  ["doi"]=>                                           
  string(6) "2KABUL"                                  
  ["dstcoll1"]=>                                      
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["dstcoll2"]=>                                      
  string(5) "KABUL"                                   
  ["dosesr"]=>                                        
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["dosesn"]=>                                        
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["doses"]=>                                         
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["dlopv"]=>                                         
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["fever"]=>                                         
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["progress"]=>                                      
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["asym"]=>                                          
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["dfup"]=>                                          
  string(3) "242"                                     
  ["fup"]=>                                           
  string(1) "A"                                       
  ["dstlab"]=>                                        
  string(10) "FGAFG/06/0"                             
  ["dtres"]=>                                         
  string(5) "6/725"                                   
  ["dires"]=>                                         
  string(6) "2KABUL"                                  
  ["stcond"]=>                                        
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["l20b"]=>                                          
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["p1"]=>                                            
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["p2"]=>                                            
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["p3"]=>                                            
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["entero"]=>                                        
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["class"]=>                                         
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["fdiag"]=>                                         
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["othdiag"]=>                                       
  string(1) "K"                                       
  ["sdiag"]=>                                         
  string(29) "AFGAFG/06/06/725       2KABUL"          
  ["contact"]=>                                       
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["eligcont"]=>                                      
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["inadafp"]=>                                       
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["hotafp"]=>                                        
  string(0) ""                                        
  ["hardarea"]=>                                      
  string(1) "K"                                       
  ["othreas"]=>                                       
  string(1) "A"                                       
  ["sothreas"]=>                                      
  string(30) "BUL                          2"         
  ["wildcont"]=>                                      
  string(1) "4"                                       
  ["vdpvcont"]=>                                      
  string(1) "2"                                       
}
```

Comment: Can you split first part and second part into 2 files? Looks like first part is whitespace delimited so i'd use `fgetcsv` for that.

Comment: No the files will be uploaded by different users and the used software dump the variables and the data in the same file `.rec` and this is just a sample the actual files consists of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are only looking at the start and length of each field relative to a single line of data in...

```
$data_row_limit = 79 - $x;
```

Each time you get past this, you reset the start to position 0 again, which is why it always extract the data from the start of the string.

If instead you just keep on adding the lengths...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfVariables; $i++) {
    $result = fgets($file);
    $variable_name = strtolower(trim(substr($result, 1, 11)));
    $current_item_length = intval(trim(substr($result, 36, 4)));
    $total_length_for_all_varibles += $current_item_length;
    $last_end = $current_item_length + intval($last_end);

    if ($current_item_length > 0) {
        if ($i === 0) {
            //first loop
            $heads[$i]['start'] = 0;//variable starts at position 0 of the row
        } else {
            $prev_start = $heads[$i - 1]['start'];
            $prev_item_length = $heads[$i - 1]['field_length'];

            // Just store position here
            $heads[$i]['start'] = $prev_start + $prev_item_length;
        }

        $heads[$i]['field_length'] = $current_item_length;
        $heads[$i]['variable_name'] = strtolower(trim($variable_name));

    }//end if length > 0
}//end for loop for getting the variables
```

I've also modified the string concatenation to remove the `!` and some other bits it may have...

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_data_rows; $i++){
    $data.= rtrim(fgets($file), "!\n\r ");
}
```